# Подскажите легковесный фреймворк на PHP

Tags: django, laravel, yii, фреймворк

Почему фреймворки на PHP такие тяжеловесные ? До этого имел дело с фреймворком Django на Python. Так он намного легче весом и проект создается за милисекунды. Есть ли что-то подобное на PHP ?

Comment: Зависит от поставленной задачи. Например микро фреймворк [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/).

Comment: @RTK мне нра ) от имени все понятно

Answer (score 0):

Взять тот же Laravel, у него есть легковесная версия Lumen.